# Is it safe to use useCnntext+useReducer to store JWT?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jwt

Is it safe to use useCnntext+useReducer to store JWT? And also what's the difference if I use redux

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

it's not about safe, it's about practicability.

JWT will be flushed by context if u reload page.

so it's better to store in localStorage or sessionStorage.

for safety issue, it's fine if you JWT key not exposed on front side.

Comment: Thanks. I think I will use memory to store refresh token and store the access token in cookie, which is recommended by many people